# How to add a bracket {} under one tag in yaml file by Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I want to make one YAML file by Python like as below.

```
A:
  B:
     c: {d:e}
```

but if I do it like as below:

```
data = {'A':{'B':{ 'c':'{d:e}'}}}
yaml.dump(data,file,default_flow_style = False)
```

the output in the file is as below:

```
A:
  B:
    c: '{d: e}'
```

I don't want the quotation around. How to do it?

Comment: Why do you think that's not the right output? Note that YAML's mappings (or [*"associative arrays"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Associative_arrays)) don't look like dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You made a string out of `{d:e}` by putting quotes around the whole thing.  Change `'{d:e}'` to `{'d':'e'}`.

```
In [57]: data = {'A':{'B':{ 'c':{'d':'e'}}}}

In [58]: print yaml.dump(data)
A:
  B:
    c: {d: e}
```